# How to turn on encryption with right_aws gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, right-aws

The right_aws documentation states:

```
put(key, data=nil, meta_headers={}, perms=nil, headers={})
```

Store object data. The key is a String or Key instance. Returns true.

```
bucket.put('logs/today/1.log', 'Olala!') #=> true
```

How does this put call match the signature?

To turn on encryption:

> ...when you are uploading a new object or making a copy of an existing object, you can specify if you want Amazon S3 to encrypt your data by adding the x-amz-server-side-encryption header to the request. Set the value of the header to the encryption algorithm AES256 that Amazon S3 supports

How do you turn on encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put(key, data=nil, meta_headers={}, perms=nil, headers={})` is the signature.

`bucket.put('logs/today/1.log', 'Olala!')` is a call without the 3rd, 4th and 5th params.

To encrypt data and set private access, use:

`bucket.put('logs/today/1.log', 'Olala!', {}, 'private', {'x-amz-server-side-encryption' => 'AES256'})`

Note that `:x-amz-server-side-encryption` will not work because it is not a valid Ruby symbol.